# How can I secure NM cable in a tight spot?

Tags: electrical

I need to secure NM cable in an area where there isn't enough room to swing a hammer. This makes the usual staples impossible to use. How can I secure the cable in this tight space?

Comment: Why do you need to secure it in this specific place? Just secure it before and after this spot.

Comment: The cable needs to make a couple of bends in this area and I need the staples to hold the bends.

Comment: I'm sure you can use other tools, even if it's not their designed usage. Press your staple in place with your fingers, hold it in place with a metal rod, plate or anything else that's rigid and will be able to transfer force without bending or shattering.

A metal dowel, perhaps? I've used old screwdrivers with the handle end pointing towards the material to be fastened, banging away happily at the driver end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get an NM cable stapler at a supply house or home center, that is if you can fit it into this area.

Also, we many times use our linemans pliers to pound staples. Sure, it's not the intended use, but in a tight spot many times they work perfectly. Hit with the face where the cutters are.

Answer (score 2):

I have pressed fasteners in using a flatbar, whenever the surrounding area would support the pressure of the flatbar levering in such things. Sometimes you can use a cable clamp and a well angled screw, might work

Comment: I have "driven" 3" nails in a 3 1/4" space using this method. Leverage and balance are critical. In your case, you can drive a 3/4" long staple in a 1 " space

Answer (score -1):

I avoid a regular hammer whenever I can and use a small air-driven palm nailer for hanging electrical boxes and staples.

My small nailer only needs roughly 4" clearance over the head of the fastener for the tool and your hand, so if you managed to install a box in the void, you ought to be able to hammer the nail-style NM staples without any difficulty.